# How to fix error when importing the blender module in Python

Tags: python, blender

i get the following error code when i import bpy into python is this because i need blender installed or can i solve this probelm another way'

```
Color management: using fallback mode for management
BLT_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
bpy: couldnt find 'scripts/modules', blender probably wont start.
Freestyle: couldn't find 'scripts/freestyle/modules', Freestyle won't work properly.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): c:\users\tgubs\.blenderpy\blender\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:6662 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): c:\users\tgubs\.blenderpy\blender\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:6662 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): c:\users\tgubs\.blenderpy\blender\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:6662 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
F1106 16:58:18.372622 23956 utilities.cc:322] Check failed: !IsGoogleLoggingInitialized() You called InitGoogleLogging() twice!
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

Comment: Blender includes and uses its own python interpreter. Usually blender is told to run its scripts directly, either within the GUI or in the background using `blender --background --python script.py` from [the CLI](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html). It is possible to [build blender as a python module](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) that can be imported in a standard python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `2.79` folder to the directory containing the python executable.

simply go into your python env, into the Scripts directory, cut the `2.79` folder out of there and paste it into the folder containing the Conda Python executable. The problem is that the version folder (`2.79`, currently) must be sibling to the Python executable. Since whatever environment you are in does not have the `python.exe` file located alongside the Scripts (`pip`, `venv`, etc) it is complaining since the path to `bpy_types` is supposed to be `./2.79/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py` (relative to the current `python.exe` that is trying to import it) and it can't find it.

Windows is a known platform where these script files can be different, especially depending on your environment.

So in short:

Find the folder `2.79`
Cut it from the current location
Paste it into the folder containing `python.exe`

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

First) `check your python version` if it's not more than 3.7 and less than <3.8
because bpy module requires `Python >=3.7, <3.8`.

Second) check (mostly i guess) C://USER//USER(your user name)//AppData//Programs//Python//Python37//Scripts directory. (just check where your python installed on your local)
there should be folder named `2.XX` (i guess it's 2.82 but it depends on your bpy version)
you should `move 2.XX folder to outside of the Scripts folder`. (in Python 37 folder)

Then it should work.